# How to get gps nmea data from Teltonika FM1100 after receiving imei code in C#

Tags: c#, gps

I am not getting gps nmea data from Teltonika FM1100 after receiving imei code in C#.Please help me

class Program
    {
        static IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.107");

```
    static TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 3306);

    static Socket s;
    public void start()
    {

        myList.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 3306...");

        Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                          myList.LocalEndpoint);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

        s = myList.AcceptSocket();

        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

        byte[] b = new byte[s.ReceiveBufferSize];

        int k = s.Receive(b);

        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)

            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
```

sending 1 byte data as acknowledgement

s.Send(asen.GetBytes("T"));

//getting the gps data after acknowledgement
            byte[] ack = new byte[s.ReceiveBufferSize];

```
        int y = Program.s.Receive(ack);

        for (int q = 0; q < y; q++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(ack[q]));
        }

        s.Close();

        myList.Stop();


    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


            Program pg = new Program();

            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pg.start));

            th.Start();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You will need to provide more then that to get good help here. What does your code look like? Is the GPS receiver recieving any coordinates itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending 1 byte data as acknowledgement

```
s.Send(asen.GetBytes("T"));
```

You need to send here `01`

like

```
byte[] msg = new byte[] { 0x01 };

s.Send(msg );
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I got the gps data, but in some unrecognizable format instead of NMEA format. like as follows☺ ☻ ♥ 3 ' E☺d P♦§♥E      ?µ ☼¶ B2♠↑  I§?I+♣☻Ç    ñ  ?o   ☺B"A♠8 /I∟??T@ ♠  ♂   ‼         

☺ ☻ ♥ 3 ' E☺d☺P♣§♥E      Aµ ☼¶ B0û↑  I§?I+♣☻Ç    ñ  ?o   ☺B"A!? /I∟??T@ ♠  ♂   ‼

☺ ☻ ♥ 3 ' E☺d☺P♣§♥E      ?µ ☼¶ B.?↑  I§?I+♣☻Ç    ñ  ?o ♥  ò§

Answer (score 0):

Teltonika FM1100 does not send ASCII NMEA data you have to know protocol Codec12 to be able to read GPS data from teltonika .